# DAC (.dac) File type

Tags: backup, exchange

Where do I find code examples for using Dac for Mysql ? 
As my DAC file stores backup of exchange mailboxes.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it was used for Exchange, isn't it more likely to be a MS SQL Server format?

Comment: In what other formats it would be like to.Any suggestions.